# Display text based on drop down selection (code works on jsfiddle but not website?)

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I am having issues with this code somewhere but can't figure it out. [Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2ukyA/39/)

```
document.getElementById('email-list').onchange = function() {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};
```

Works fine on there but I can get it to work on either of two different websites local on wamp or live. Am I missing something?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @ZachL I can't find any in the console in inspector but jslint throws some errors that I am honestly not sure how to correct. I am new to javascript

Comment: fyi, adding an event listener like that is not X-browser friendly, and probably will not work at all in IE. I personally prefer using a library (like jQuery) to handle event delegation.

Comment: @ZachL: Which browser doesn't support assigning an event to the `on[event]` propert of an element?

Comment: no worries. JSlint errors aren't really "errors", just heavy-handed opinions how to write your code.

Comment: @amnotiam hmm, I may be confused having too briefly skimmed [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange).  But surely all browser implementations of this are not equal.

Comment: Could I possibly be missing something that jsfiddle is automatically adding?

Comment: Can't tell what your issue is with your site if you don't post the code. Could be a DOM-ready issue. Could be something else. Your jsfiddle is running the code after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS Fiddle example works because you have selected `onload` option in JsFiddle. So
Make sure you have wrapped your code with `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('email-list').onchange = function() {
    var i = 1;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(i);
    while(myDiv) {
        myDiv.style.display = 'none';
        myDiv = document.getElementById(++i);
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
}};
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2ukyA/41/)

Comment: ahh, that could be it.  Alternatively, you can add the script at the end of the body to be sure the html has been loaded.